# How to split a slice in Go in sub-slices

Tags: arrays, go, split, slice

I'm recently using Go to create applications. My question is this: at a certain point in the program I have a string slice:

```
my_slice = []string{"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6"}
```

It contains 6 strings. Which is the best procedure (easier to write and understand) to break this slice into 3 parts, for example, and distribute the content in three sub-slices?
If I have:

```
var my_sub_slice1 []string
var my_sub_slice2 []string
var my_sub_slice3 []string
```

I wish at the end of it `my_sub_slice1` will contain (in his first two entries) `"string1","string2"`; `my_sub_slice2` will contain (in his first two entries) `"string3","string4"`; `my_sub_slice3` will contain (in his first two entries) `"string5","string6"`.
I know the question is easy but I haven't found a clean and efficient way to do this yet.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Slice the original slice. [Go Tour: Slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)

Answer (score 10):

A general solution to split a slice to into sub-slices of equal length

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
size := 2
var j int
for i := 0; i < len(s); i += size{
    j += size
    if j > len(s) {
        j = len(s)
    }
    // do what do you want to with the sub-slice, here just printing the sub-slices
    fmt.Println(s[i:j])
}

// output
// [1 2]
// [3 4]
// [5 6]
// [7 8]
// [9 10]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my_sub_slice1 := my_slice[0:2]
my_sub_slice2 := my_slice[2:4]
my_sub_slice3 := my_slice[4:6]
```

Comment: This is a better approach.

Comment: Beware that modifying contents of any of my_sub_sliceX, you will ALSO modify contents of original my_slice. Because subslicing does not involve data copy.

If you need to create separate copy of data, use `append`:

my_sub_slice1 := append([]string{}, my_slice[0:2]...)